# Why someone use this?

Tags: grammar

I heard some sentences with this form from English speakers: "what I *do* know is that..." or 
" We *do* share the same..."
The question is: what is the applicant of *do* in these sentences? Why they use it before main verbs?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the many uses of "do-support", which is worth researching generally.

In this case it either adds emphasis, or contrasts with a previous negative:

> I don't know if the case you are thinking of contrasted with a previous negative, but I do know this sentence does.